# function to calculating the difference between months where the values are positioned verticallyusing python pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which shows a number of items (AMT) collected by Month (Month).

I know how to create a new column which calculates the difference between two vertical columns I.e New Column = Amount -2.

I don't know how to create a function to calculate a column, "difference" between two months when the values are vertical, for example: Feb - Jan would be 11-10 = 1.

In excel you could make a formula which points to a cell to get the first value, and offset it by one row to get the second.

However I don't know of an offset function for pandas python, or another way to calculate this with data that's in a vertical fashion?

```
Month   Amt Difference
Jan     10   0 (as there is no previous month to compare it with)
Feb     11   1
Mar     15   4
Apr     12   -3
May     17
Jun     10
Jul     30
Aug     31
Sep     32
Oct     10
Nov     25
Dec     30
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to make use of the indexes, locating the `Amt` value from the previous index and subtract them, like this:

```
 df['Diff'] = [df.loc[x, "Amt"] - df.loc[x-1 if x>0 else 0, "Amt"] 
               for x in df.index]

In [98]: df
Out[98]: 
   Month  Amt  Diff
0    Jan   10     0
1    Feb   11     1
2    Mar   15     4
3    Apr   12    -3
4    May   17     5
5    Jun   10    -7
6    Jul   30    20
7    Aug   31     1
8    Sep   32     1
9    Oct   10   -22
10   Nov   25    15
11   Dec   30     5
```

To extend on above, you can build the index of `df` from `Month` which will be list of strings, then locating by enumerate the indexes, that is:

```
df = df.set_index('Month')
idx = df.index

df['Diff'] = [df.loc[x, "Amt"] - df.loc[idx[i-1] if i>0 else idx[0], "Amt"] 
              for i, x in enumerate(idx)]
```

The idea is to have the indexes on hand, locating the column and grab its index, then calculate the difference based on *previous* index (if not the first column).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.diff()` function in `pandas` to do it in one step. Lets say `df` is your pandas dataframe:

```
>> df['Diff'] = df['Amt'].diff().fillna(0)
>> print df
   Month  Amt  Diff
0    Jan   10     0
1    Feb   11     1
2    Mar   15     4
3    Apr   12    -3
4    May   17     5
5    Jun   10    -7
6    Jul   30    20
7    Aug   31     1
8    Sep   32     1
9    Oct   10   -22
10   Nov   25    15
11   Dec   30     5
```